# ROS Answers SE migration: stage on os x

Tags: simulation, stage, macos-snowleopard, ros-electric, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
after the successful installation of rviz_qt, I tried to make Stage4 to work with the new rviz_qt as mentioned in [this post](http://williamjwoodall.com/2011/09/23/ros-and-stage4-on-os-x/). I have applied patches [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/attachment/ticket/5187/stage-r37964-osx.patch) and [here](https://github.com/wjwwood/ros-osx/blob/master/electric-lion-homebrew/patches/stage-1.4.0-homebrew-svn.patch),successfully installed Stage4 by homebrew. However I have got the same problem which is mentioned [here](https://github.com/wjwwood/ros-osx/tree/master/electric-lion-homebrew). My question is, since I have already had the Stage4 installed, why shall I still have to compile stage from source? My understand is Stage4 is a standalone simulator, and stageros is just a ros wrapper of stage. When working together, stageros node provides interface between ros and stage. Is it right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12387/stage-on-os-x/) by [cnhzcy14](https://answers.ros.org/users/1411/cnhzcy14/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2011-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would assume that you are either on diamondback or electric; both of these ROS distributions provide Stage 3.2.2 and not Stage 4.X.X. What I understand from [Woodall's blog](http://williamjwoodall.com/2011/09/23/ros-and-stage4-on-os-x/), is that his installation of stage/stageros provided with ROS did did not work on OS-X that is why he went on to install Stage 4.X.X separately and then he probably linked it up with ROS.

Yes, you are right stage is standalone, stageros is the wrapper for ROS, see here - http://answers.ros.org/question/2004/what-are-the-differences-between-stage-and.

Hope that answers your question.

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2011-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-12-20**:
@cnhzcy14 : Cheers dude ! Anytime ....

**Comment by [cnhzcy14](https://answers.ros.org/users/1411/cnhzcy14/) on 2011-12-19**:
That's really helpful! Thanks!

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-12-18**:
@cnhzcy14: Also, moving from Stage 3.X.X to 4.X.X has some changes in the syntax, see here - http://blog.aus10.org/?p=125

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-12-17**:
@cnhzcy14 : Stage 4.X.X is standalone and the official repository is this - https://github.com/rtv/Stage/downloads  this will give you Stage 4.0.1, if you check the git code here - https://github.com/rtv/Stage that will give you Stage 4.1.0.

**Comment by [cnhzcy14](https://answers.ros.org/users/1411/cnhzcy14/) on 2011-12-17**:
Yes, I have electric installed on OS X 10.6 by homebrew approach, and thank you for you help. Now I have new questions. First, is the link to Stage4 breakdown? Second, since Stage4 is stand alone, why there are still some lines about stage installation in CMakeLists.txt?